# How do I create Tetris Blocks in XNA with C#?

Tags: c#, xna, tetris

I'm making a Tetris Clone in C# with XNA, and I'm unsure of how to actually implement the blocks.

I don't think that making the shapes as images will work (because parts are removed when lines are formed), so I Have blocks to make up the pieces like [This](http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/4719/jsquarebig.png).

Unfortunately, I don't know how to actually define the blocks to make the pieces, nor do I know how to manipulate them to make them rotate, etc.

Edit: I would also need assistance in learning how to make the Tetris Grid too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't created tetris before, but after some thinking, I believe that I would use a simple matrix to create my pieces.  For example, your whole game board would be one big matrix.  A subset of that matrix, say a 4x4 block of it, would be a game piece.  Which parts of that 4x4 block would be filled would be determined by which particular piece you want to create.  Each part of the matrix can have a boolean flag that would indicate if it's filled or not.  This is a very simplistic view of it, but I think it's a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean matrix to model the state of the screen. Each piece is itself another smaller boolean matrix.

Rotating a piece is as simple as playing with the coordinates a little bit (I left this to you).

About how to render, just draw a piece tile for each true value in your matrix `ored` with the current falling piece shifted and rotated.

Answer (score 1):

For the blocks, I would strongly suggest working in 3D. You can still make the game look like 2D by locking the camera etc, but you will benefit a lot from working in vector graphics. Your blocks will be simple cubes (flat or with some depth) that you rotate and move around the screen.

For the grid, look at @fortran's and @aaron's answers, a boolean matrix will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link to [Coding4Fun](http://www.microsoft.com/germany/msdn/coding4fun/projekte/xna/projekt_tetris.mspx) will help. It's in german, but you should be able to get the source code and take a look on how about the problem is solved here.

Just to be sure, here the [direct download link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/2/5/325fd01e-437b-47d6-8e07-1ae66529b78b/XnaTetris_Code.zip).